# Counting in php and Displaying information on website

Tags: php, mysql

I new at php programming and the question I have is about counting. I search around different website and could not come up direct answers on counting. Now what I am trying to do is make a website where you enter data and displays a table with that information in it. I got it to work for must part in displaying data now. Now I need it to count or sum one column in my database and display the answer in another field on the table when data comes up a second or third time.

Here is example of my code that I am working with:

```
    $sql = "Select * FROM modems";
    $query = $db->prepare( $sql );
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

    $return = "Select SUM(maddress) FROM modems";
    $query = $db->prepare( $return);
    $query->execute();


    ?>

   <!---Table class that creates a table--->
   <table class="table">
   <caption>Modem Results Page</caption>
   <tr>
   <th>Mac Address</th>
   <th>Modem Model Number</th>
   <th>Date</th>
   <th>Reported Problem</th>
   <th>Good or Bad</th>
   <th>Initials</th>
   <th>Times Returned</th>
   </tr>

   <input type='button' value='Return to Modems Page'          onclick="location.href='modems.php'"><br><br>

<!---Populates data in the table--->
<?php foreach( $results as $row){
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['maddress'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['mmodel'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['date'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['mproblem'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['good_bad'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['initials'];
    echo "</td><td>";
    echo $row['SUM(maddress)'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

The problem that I have is nothing displaying in times returned part of website, I know that problem is the second query not sure how to end it to get it to display correctly and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Jonathan

Comment: You don't fetch the results of your second query.

Comment: I added the this to the second query: $return = $query->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); It still does not display the information at all on the webpage. Not sure if there is anther fetch that I should be using thanks for you help.

Comment: Now that you've got the result, you need to use it in the table. Remove the SUM you have in the `foreach` loop and, for starters, just put a `var_dump()`, of the result of the second query, at the end of your script. Go step by step. Be careful with the choice of variable names, they might clash if you make them the same.

Comment: Now I removed the sum from the foreach loop. Not sure were to put the var_dump at in my code. I put it here: $return = $query->var_dump($return); Now it does not show the table at all on my page.

Comment: That's because you cannot use `var_dump()` like that. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php Just write: `var_dump($return);`. Always look up these things, if you don't know them. Even a simple google on 'php var_dump' will give you the answer.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.